# How does the G&FH Twitter account work?

Tags: discussion, publicity

The [G&FH Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackGenealogy) account currently has 14 followers. Do you think it would be a good thing to also "follow" some of the big genealogy buffs that are adept at utilizing social media? The account currently is following "0" other Twitter users. I, myself, usually link to other people that are linked to people I already know and trust.

Does one of the moderators manage this account? Is it set up by Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the Twitter account is totally automated -- the moderators don't have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

The Twitter account is automated. It is run by a SE bot which picks up tweets based on some algorithm.

The Tweets are currently not controllable by moderators<sup>*</sup>. They can however be selectively removed by the Community Team.

<sub>* [Change requested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/189539/200868)</sub>

Comment: **based on some algorithm** is an exceptionally eloquent description of the problem!

Comment: @Fortiter Thanks :P Some parts are easy to guess though, it picks new questions <48 hours old (max priority) with score >=1 at the time. Other than that, it picks up exceptionally good answers (>10 votes) as well, but rarely IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get followers on Twitter, follow some other people.  I have just become the first twitter follower.

Comment: Our Twitter account is totally automated -- it *can't* follow anyone. (Although it has 18 followers)